# Tabs with scrolling animated header - React native

Tags: android, ios, animation, react-native

I am following the tutorial in the link: https://medium.com/appandflow/react-native-scrollview-animated-header-10a18cb9469e .
However I can't seem to understand how to add tabs to this such that the tab headers get fixed to top when scrolled up. Can anyone please suggest how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve it using ScrollableTab and Tab in native-base library.

Code looks like this

```js
<Tabs
  prerenderingSiblingsNumber={3}
  onChangeTab={({ i }) => {
    this.setState({ height: this.heights[i], activeTab: i })
  }}
  renderTabBar={(props) => (
    <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ translateY: tabY }], zIndex: 1, width: "100%", backgroundColor: "white", paddingTop: HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT }}>
      <ScrollableTab 
        {...props}
        renderTab={(name, page, active, onPress, onLayout) => (
          <TouchableOpacity key={page}
            onPress={() => onPress(page)}
            onLayout={onLayout}
            activeOpacity={0.4}>
            <Animated.View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                height: 100,
                backgroundColor: tabBg
              }}>
              <TabHeading scrollable
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: "transparent",
                  width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2
                }}
                active={active}>
                <Animated.Text style={{
                  fontWeight: active ? "bold" : "normal",
                  color: 'black',
                  padding: 10,
                  fontSize: active ? 20 : 18
                }}>
                  {name}
                </Animated.Text>
              </TabHeading>
            </Animated.View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
        underlineStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'black' }} 
      />
    </Animated.View>
  )}>
  <Tab heading="Tab 1">
    {this.tabContent(30, 0)}
  </Tab>
  <Tab heading="Tab 2">
    {this.tabContent(15, 1)}
  </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a working example on Expo? I am trying to get your code running but only get errors.

Comment: Please see this: https://blog.expo.io/implementation-complex-animation-in-react-native-by-example-search-bar-with-tab-view-and-collapsing-68bb43be2dcb

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated
```

Then basic usage look like this to replace in `<Animated.View ......<Text>....</Text>..... ></Animated.View>`:

```
<TabView
  navigationState={{ index, routes }}
  onIndexChange={setIndex}
  renderScene={SceneMap({
    first: FirstRoute,
    second: SecondRoute,
  })}
/>
```

I hope it'll help you..!

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else falls on this thread, I developed a new package, **react-native-animated-screen**, that does exactly what you need

Check it out

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-animated-screen

[image]

```js
import  React  from  'react';
import { Image, Text, View } from  'react-native';
import AnimatedScreen from  'react-native-animated-screen';

const  Component = () => {
   return (
     <AnimatedScreen.Wrapper>
       <AnimatedScreen.Header>
         <View>
           <Text>Title</Text>
           <AnimatedScreen.CollapsibleElement>
             <Text>Subtitle</Text>
           </AnimatedScreen.CollapsibleElement>
           <AnimatedScreen.Element>
            <YourTabsComponen /> 
           </AnimatedScreen.Element>
         </View>
       </AnimatedScreen.Header>
       <AnimatedScreen.ScrollView>
         <View  style={{ height: '300%' }}>
           <View>
             <Text>Body</Text>
           </View>
         </View>
       </AnimatedScreen.ScrollView>
     </AnimatedScreen.Wrapper>
   );
};
```

In the example above only the title and `YourTabBComponent`are going to remain after scrolling, the subtitle (as all the elements wrapped in a CollapsibleElement) will disappear.

Ideally you could also have the tabs to appear only when entirely scrolled using the interpolate prop or the animatedStyle of the AnimatedScreen.Element

```js
// using interpolate the animation will flow from 0 to scrollY === headerMaxHeight 
<AnimatedScreen.Element interpolate={{ opacity: [0, 1], height: [0, 60] }}>
  <TabComponent />
</AnimatedScreen.Element>

// alternatevely you can have more control with an animatedStyle

<AnimatedScreen.Element animatedStyle={scrollY => ({
  opacity: scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [100, 200],
    outputRange: [0, 1]
    extrapolate: 'clamp'
  })
})}>
  <TabComponent />
</AnimatedScreen.Element>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else falls on this thread, I developed a new package, **react-native-animated-screen**, that does exactly what you need

Check it out

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-animated-screen

[image]

```js
import  React  from  'react';
import { Image, Text, View } from  'react-native';
import AnimatedScreen from  'react-native-animated-screen';

const  Component = () => {
   return (
     <AnimatedScreen.Wrapper>
       <AnimatedScreen.Header>
         <View>
           <Text>Title</Text>
           <AnimatedScreen.CollapsibleElement>
             <Text>Subtitle</Text>
           </AnimatedScreen.CollapsibleElement>
           <AnimatedScreen.Element>
            <YourTabsComponen /> 
           </AnimatedScreen.Element>
         </View>
       </AnimatedScreen.Header>
       <AnimatedScreen.ScrollView>
         <View  style={{ height: '300%' }}>
           <View>
             <Text>Body</Text>
           </View>
         </View>
       </AnimatedScreen.ScrollView>
     </AnimatedScreen.Wrapper>
   );
};
```

In the example above only the title and `YourTabBComponent`are going to remain after scrolling, the subtitle (as all the elements wrapped in a CollapsibleElement) will disappear.

Ideally you could also have the tabs to appear only when entirely scrolled using the interpolate prop or the animatedStyle of the AnimatedScreen.Element

```js
// using interpolate the animation will flow from 0 to scrollY === headerMaxHeight 
<AnimatedScreen.Element interpolate={{ opacity: [0, 1], height: [0, 60] }}>
  <TabComponent />
</AnimatedScreen.Element>

// alternatevely you can have more control with an animatedStyle

<AnimatedScreen.Element animatedStyle={scrollY => ({
  opacity: scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [100, 200],
    outputRange: [0, 1]
    extrapolate: 'clamp'
  })
})}>
  <TabComponent />
</AnimatedScreen.Element>
```